# mySQL - the right way to put in the column (UNION or other?)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to figure out WHY its giving me 2 rows instead of 1, as you can see in row '0130'.  Basically what I'm trying to do is get Enemy Name and check based on # of Alliance in Server AND State (depending on what user select, Server will always be the WHOLE number whereas State varies).

First UNION shows the WHOLE Server (always the same number)
Second UNION shows Depending on State selected by user (random number based on group by)

Unless my thought in Query is WAYYY off, I would love to hear what is the proper way to do so!

```
SELECT
    ASEnemy,ASFlagStatus,COUNT(SCAlliance) Server,0 State
    FROM AllianceStatus
    INNER JOIN SC75 ON (SCAlliance = ASEnemy AND SCSnap = (SELECT MAX(DSSnap) FROM DataSnap WHERE DSServer = 75))
    WHERE ASServer = 75
    AND ASOurs = '1057'
    AND (((SCFieldID % 800) >= 0 AND (SCFieldID % 800) <= 799) AND (FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) >= 0 AND FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) <= 799))
    GROUP BY BINARY SCAlliance
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ASEnemy,ASFlagStatus,0 Server,COUNT(SCAlliance) State
    FROM AllianceStatus
    INNER JOIN SC75 ON (SCAlliance = ASEnemy AND SCSnap = (SELECT MAX(DSSnap) FROM DataSnap WHERE DSServer = 75))
    WHERE ASServer = 75
    AND ASOurs = '1057'
    AND (((SCFieldID % 800) >= 400 AND (SCFieldID % 800) <= 599) AND (FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) >= 600 AND FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) <= 799))
    GROUP BY BINARY SCAlliance
    ORDER BY ASFlagStatus,BINARY ASEnemy
LIMIT 100
```

Example Current Output with mySQL above:

```
ASEnemy ASFlag  Server  State
000001  1       398         0
0130    1       699         0
0130    1       0           263
04      1       240         0
04      1       0           22
08      1       456         0
08      1       0           3
1001    1       870         0
1001    1       0           438
```

The output I would like to see is:

```
ASEnemy ASFlag  Server  State
000001  1       398         0
0130    1       699         263
04      1       240         22
08      1       456         3
1001    1       870         438
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output you want you could either wrap your original query in another that gets the max values per group:

```
SELECT ASEnemy, ASFlagStatus, MAX(Server) Server, MAX(State) State
FROM (
-- your original query here
) src
GROUP BY ASEnemy, ASFlagStatus
```

Or you could rewrite it and use conditional aggregation by moving the part of the conditions that differ inside a case expression in the count function.

It should probably look something like this (but I obviously have tested it as there were no sample data to test with):

```
SELECT
 ASEnemy,
 ASFlagStatus,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN (((SCFieldID % 800) >= 0 AND (SCFieldID % 800) <= 799) AND (FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) >= 0 AND FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) <= 799)) THEN SCAlliance ELSE NULL END) Server,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN (((SCFieldID % 800) >= 400 AND (SCFieldID % 800) <= 599) AND (FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) >= 600 AND FLOOR(SCFieldID / 800) <= 799)) THEN SCAlliance ELSE NULL END) State
FROM AllianceStatus
INNER JOIN SC75 ON (SCAlliance = ASEnemy AND SCSnap = (SELECT MAX(DSSnap) FROM DataSnap WHERE DSServer = 75))
WHERE ASServer = 75
  AND ASOurs = '1057'
GROUP BY BINARY SCAlliance
ORDER BY ASFlagStatus,BINARY ASEnemy
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: oh wow, never thought to use COUNT(xxxx) in SCFieldID.. That most certainly make sense and tested the mySQL Query.. I can safely say it works like charm.